# Pressure Plates and Chat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating an adventure map for a friend, and I want a pressure plate to bring up instructions in the chat when he steps on it. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not a good website for suggestions. I recommend you go to Forums or Reddit.

Comment: Have you even tried working this out yourself before you asked here? A Google search for 'Minecraft command print to chat' probably would have given you the correct answer

Comment: You may want to read through this https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/what-to-do-before-asking-a-minecraft-commands-question

Answer (score 4):

You can set a command block's command to `/say Instructions go here` and make the pressure plate trigger that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an option that is more editable than /say (color, bold, italic, or clickable settings), use the /tellraw command.

```
 /tellraw [player] [json messasge]
```

For example, this message will be red (&c):

```
/tellraw @a {text:"This Is a message",color:"red"}
```

Answer (score 0):

do **/tell** **@p** "Instructions" or if you want it for both people do **/say** "Instructions" Or if you have essentials installed you can do **/message** or **/broadcast**. message will tell one player. **broadcast will say in chat for all server like /say.**